# How can I get my website to enable gzip compression?

Tags: htaccess, page-speed, compression, gzip

I'm currently trying to increase the speed of my website and I noticed that, when I run it through `ismyblogworking.com`, I get a message that reads "your blog application doesn't support gzip compression."

Since then, I've tried quite a few things to enable gzip compression. I've updated my Wordpress to 3.8.1 (the most recent update), I've installed W3 Total Cache and I've added the follow code to my *.htaccess*:

```
compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddType x-font/otf .otf
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddType x-font/eot .eot
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/png .png
```

However, I'm still getting the same warning sign, still ranking low for PageSpeed Insights. Can anybody give me some advice as to what I should be doing here? How can I get a WordPress site to enable gzip compression?

Comment: before getting into details about the rules on the .htaccess, have you asked on your hosting company if they support compression and what kind?

Comment: I haven't, although they are Bluehost which seem to be widely recommended for Wordpress, so I would expect they would. Is it common for hosting companies to disallow this?

Comment: Many companies disable compression because of the overload it generates on the server. Specially poorly coded sites. Also, other hostings disable it by default but they enable it on a per user/site basis. I have no experience with them, so I can't say what they do, but I'd ask there first, it should be 5 minutes or less on a live chat.

Comment: Just to be sure, the first line in your code block `compress text, ...` is commented out (ie. `#`)? Or does not exist in your actual .htaccess code?

Answer (score 4):

Put these lines in your *.htaccess* and PageSpeed Insights will see your gzip compression:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It works for my sites.

Comment: Thanks. I already have this.  
`<IfModule mod_deflate.c>  
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain  text/xmltext/css application/x-javascript  
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html  
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip  
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html  
</IfModule>`  
Should I delete it and replace it with your code?

Comment: Indeed, you can replace your code by the one I propose.

Comment: And should I also switch off any cache plug-ins that I have installed on my Wordpress?

Comment: Your intuition is good; indeed, several WordPress plugins can update the _.htaccess_ file. Try to apply my code and keep switch on your plugin. It manages other things I suppose. If it doesn't work, try to deactivate the gzip compression on your plugin and if it's not possible, switch off it.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Added it, but the gzip compression has been undetected so far. Actually, the only thing that worked was a plugin called Force Gzip, but that slowed my site down to half the original speed...

Comment: Try to deactivate all your plugins and apply my code.

Comment: Should I remove the code in my original post as well, the AddOutputFilterByType stuff? Thanks for all your help, by the way. I understand I'm rather 'overstaying my welcome' with my comments here.

Comment: Remove all the code of your original post and put mine in your _.htaccess_.